# gnuplot: How to get a file list with non-ANSI characters?

Tags: windows, utf-8, character-encoding, gnuplot

I would like to load several files into gnuplot (under Windows).
For this I use the command `system()`. Check the follow minimal example.
This works fine as long as there are only ANSI characters in the filenames.

Well, the greek and kyrillic alphabet might be extreme cases but characters, like ä,ö,ü,ß,é,à,ñ, ... would be nice to be handled correctly.

Of course, I could:

- rename the files to contain only ANSI-characters (not really an option)
- create a file of filenames with external tools and save it as utf-8 file and load this file list into gnuplot (to be avoided if possible)
- create such a file of filenames with gnuplot using `set print`, however, gnuplot seems to save the file as ANSI encoded.

Is there a direct solution with gnuplot to handle these special characters?

**Code:**

```
### get a file list from a directory (Windows)
reset session
set encoding utf8

PATH = 'CountryTest\'
GetFileList(p,f) = sprintf('dir /b "%s%s"', p, f)

FILES = system(GetFileList(PATH,'*.dat'))
print FILES

set print "Countries.txt"
    print FILES
set print
### end of code
```

**Result1:** (gnuplot 5.2.8 console, encoding utf8)

```
Belgi�.dat
C�te d'Ivoire.dat
Espa�a.dat
L�tzebuerg.dat
M�xico.dat
Panam�.dat
Per�.dat
Rom�nia.dat
T�rkiye.dat
�ire.dat
�sland.dat
�sterreich.dat
Cesko.dat
?????.dat
??????.dat
```

**Result2:** (file `Countries.txt` created by gnuplot, Notepad++ tells me that the file is ANSI encoded)

```
Belgi‰.dat
C“te d'Ivoire.dat
Espa¤a.dat
L‰tzebuerg.dat
M‚xico.dat
Panam .dat
Per£.dat
Romƒnia.dat
Trkiye.dat
ire.dat
Ösland.dat
™sterreich.dat
Cesko.dat
?????.dat
??????.dat
```

**Update:**

If I type the following in the Windows console:

```
chcp 65001 && dir /b "CountryTest\*.dat" > "CountryTest\Countries.txt"
```

I get the file `Countries.txt`:

```
België.dat
Côte d’Ivoire.dat
España.dat
Lëtzebuerg.dat
México.dat
Panamá.dat
Perú.dat
România.dat
Türkiye.dat
Éire.dat
Ísland.dat
Österreich.dat
Česko.dat
Ελλάς.dat
Россия.dat
```

However, if I use the same command in a gnuplot script:

```
system('chcp 65001 && dir /b "CountryTest\*.dat" > "CountryTest\Countries.txt"')
```

I get this file `Countries.txt`:

```
Belgi‰.dat
C“te d'Ivoire.dat
Espa¤a.dat
L‰tzebuerg.dat
M‚xico.dat
Panam .dat
Per£.dat
Romƒnia.dat
Trkiye.dat
ire.dat
Ösland.dat
™sterreich.dat
Cesko.dat
?????.dat
??????.dat
```

So, what is going wrong with gnuplot's `system()` command?

Comment: It's a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case of the following kind (a _Python_ example): `'ä,ö,ü,ß,é,à,ñ,ë,ô,ú,â,Ö'.encode('cp850').decode('cp1252','ignore')` returns `'„,”,,á,‚,…,¤,‰,“,£,ƒ,™'`.

Comment: ok, but how will this solve my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to user @ItWasn'tMe on [superuser](https://superuser.com/a/1610723/926053), I ended up with a solution which probably cannot be improved further unless there will be a direct implementation in gnuplot.

**Starting point:** (a subdirectory `CountryTest\` with the following file names)

```
België.dat
Côte d’Ivoire.dat
España.dat
Lëtzebuerg.dat
México.dat
Panamá.dat
Perú.dat
România.dat
Türkiye.dat
Éire.dat
Ísland.dat
Österreich.dat
Česko.dat
Ελλάς.dat
Россия.dat
```

**Code:** (tested with Windows 10 and gnuplot >=5.2.0)

```
### get UTF8 file list into a datablock (Windows)
reset session

# get UTF8 filenames of a filtered directory (Windows only)
GetFileList(p,f,d) = sprintf('<ECHO %s ^<^<EOD & <CON: chcp 65001 >nul & cmd.exe /c dir /b "%s%s"', d, p, f)

PATH = 'CountryTest\'
EXPR = '*.dat'

load GetFileList(PATH, EXPR, '$myFiles')

set offsets 1,1,1,1

plot $myFiles u 0:0:($Data[$0+1]) w labels notitle
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: @ItWasn'tMe thank you for the suggestion. Fortunately, gnuplot has a substring function to easily remove `.dat` if necessary.

Comment: @ItWasn'tMe oh, you deleted your first comment and suggestion? I think it still can be helpful to know how to do it with Windows command line. Maybe you can add it again?

Comment: luckily, I found your suggestion on another unrefreshed browser:   suggestion to try `print system('<con: chcp 65001 >nul & cmd.exe /c "for %i in (*.dat)do echo\%~ni"')` if you need omit the file extensions in output... possible need some gnuplot escaping.. in %

Comment: @thoezh oh, I was thinking that my comments were superfluous/useless... sorry to have deleted...